# Why a globle pointer can't re-point to another object, but a local pointer can?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm new to C especially new to C pointers. The problem here is simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *p1 = "Hello";
char *p2;
p2 = "world";  // error: redefinition of 'p2' with a different type: 'int' vs 'char *'

int main()
{
   char *p3 = "Hello";
   char *p4;
   p4 = "world";  // OK!  p4 can re-point to somewhere
   
   return  0;
}
```

I declare a global pointer `p2`, but I try to assign a string, `"hello"`，to it.
But QT prompt a **error:** redefinition of 'p2' with a different type: 'int' vs 'char *'

It says `p2` is a `int`? But I clearly declared it a `char *`;

However, `p4`, as a local pointer, can do the same thing! All works fine in `main` function.

What's going on?  I'm confusing!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's going on is you can't run code at global scope. Only static initializers allowed, and they must be compile-time constants.

Works:

```
char *p2;
int main()
{
    p2 = "world";
}
```

The error message might not be the most helpful in this case. The only thing that can exist at global scope is a declaration or a definition (with optional initializer), so the compier thinks `p2 = "world"` is declaring `p2` to be a new variable, gives it the implicit type `int`, and then sees that conflicts with the declaration of `p2` immediately above and complains.

Comment: Thank's your reply, now `p2` plays around as it wants. :)

Answer (score 3):

Instructions, like assignment in this case, can exist only in functions. Outside of functions you can only declare or define variables, types or other functions.

So when you say `p2 = "world";` outside of a function, the compiler assumes through process of elimination that you must be declaring a variable, and since you didn't give it a type, it assumes you mean `int`. So the code you wrote is equivalent to:

```c
char *p1 = "Hello";
char *p2;
int p2 = "world";  // error: redefinition of 'p2' with a different type: 'int' vs 'char *'
```

At this point it should be obvious why it's telling you you're redefining `p2` as an `int`.

Comment: And I was just adding text that kinda goes in the path of your answer as you posted ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm clear now. That's helpful. C implicitly assumes a variable `int` if no type given. What a globle scope variable can do is declaration or definition.